# Best way to calculate unit roots of GF(n)

Tags: finite-fields

What's the best and most simple way to calculate unit roots of $GF(n)$.

$n$ could be any integer.

Please make a distinction between primes and non-primes.

**Example:**

- Show that $GF(29)$ has 7th units roots.
- How much 7th unit roots does
  $GF(29)$ have?

Comment: Hint: the multiplicative group $GF(n)\setminus\{0\}$ is always cyclic of order $n-1$, and the $k$th roots of unity in $GF(n)$ are exactly the elements of order dividing $k$ in this group.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do the following.

- All the non-zero elements $z\in GF(29)$ satisfy the equation $z^{28}=1$.
- So if $z\in GF(29), z\neq0$, then $w=z^4$ satistifies the equation $w^7=1$ because $w^7=(z^4)^7=z^{28}=1$.

This suggest an algorithm for finding a seventh root of unity:

1. Pick an arbitrary element $z\in GF(29),z\neq0$.
2. Calculate $w=z^4$. If $w\neq1$, then $w$ is a primitive seventh root of unity (primitivity depends on seven being a prime number - in a more general setting you need to do more tests).
3. Once you find a primitive seventh root of unity $w$, its powers will also be seventh roots of unity (primitive unless equal to $1$).

The method generalizes to the problem of finding $d$th root of unity in the field $GF(q)$, where $d\mid q-1$. If $d$ is not a prime, you need those extra tests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the clue: whether the order of the field is prime or not makes no difference.  It just depends on $n-1$, the order of the multiplicative group (which is cyclic).  So you can think of this group being generated by some element $\alpha$, for which $\alpha^{n-1} = 1$.  Now try to use this to determine what other types of roots there might be.